# merging two text files into one using batch or perl script

Tags: perl, shell, batch-file

Hello I am new to scripting and searching for a solution. I have two text files with different names and i want to merge them together into a new third text file. The format of each text file will be exactly same and will be like that. each text file will have some (same number of) rows starting with # sign followed by some text. after those rows starting with # signs. I will have rows starting with numbers. these rows will have numbers in three columns separated by space. The numbers in the first two columns will be the same in both files while the numbers in the third column will be different. after few hundred rows i might have rows starting with # sign again followed by rows starting with numbers in three columns like before and this can repeat many times. now here is what i want to do. 
I want to create a new text file which will have the rows starting with # sign copied exactly from the first text file. I want to copy the first two columns of numbers exactly as they are. these two columns can be copied from the first text file or the 2nd text file as they will be the same inboth files. Now for the  third column in the new text file I want to do add the number in the third column of the first two files

number in third column of new text file = (number in third column of first file + number in third column of 2nd file)

after some rows i might have rows with # sign again and then rows followed by numbers in 3 columns. and this can repeat.

sample Format of only one text file is given below. the 2nd text file will have exact same format.

```
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
 0.0   0.0 4.4226
 0.0   5.0 4.4246
 0.0  10.0 4.4456
 0.0  15.0 4.4876
 0.0  20.0 4.4453
 0.0  25.0 5.6585
 .
 .
 .
 .
# 
# 
#
# 
#
 0.0   0.0 0.410135
 0.0   5.0 0.745745
 0.0  10.0 0.574555
 0.0  15.0 0.415675
 0.0  20.0 0.575454
 0.0  25.0 0.410135
 0.0  30.0 0.678768
 0.0  35.0 0.410135
 0.0  40.0 0.976876
 0.0  45.0 0.678678
 0.0  50.0 0.410135
 0.0  55.0 0.678976
 0.0  60.0 0.410135
 0.0  65.0 0.687876
 0.0  70.0 0.768677
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

and this format of rows with # sign and numbers in three columns can repeat. the rows with numbers in three columns has columns separated by spaces and in the beginning of the these rows with numbers there is one space as well.
I hope i did a good job explaining. I prefer bacth script as it will be easy for me to run. however perl will also work. Thank you very much for your help. highly appreciated.

New file format will be exactly the same as the other two files with third column being the sum of numbers in third column of the first and 2nd txt files. sample third file format is given below.

```
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
 0.0   0.0 8.4355
 0.0   5.0 6.3553
 0.0  10.0 6.4327
 .
 .
 .
 .
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
 0.0   0.0 4.832735
 0.0   5.0 7.436343
 0.0  10.0 0.323325
 0.0  15.0 4.876656
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

Once again thank you very much. I am getting headaches because as i have a lot of these files. your help is much appreciated.

File 1 is here

```
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
#
# 
 0.0   0.0 5.30562
 0.0   5.0 5.30562
 0.0  10.0 1.4852
90.0 355.0 1.99511
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
 0.0   0.0 0.948027
 0.0   5.0 0.948027
90.0 355.0 1.54
```

file 2 is

```
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
 0.0   0.0 1.4621
 0.0   5.0 1.4621
 0.0  10.0 1.4621
90.0 355.0 3.3359
# 
# 
# 
# 
# 
 0.0   0.0 0.747458
 0.0   5.0 0.747458
90.0 355.0 0.550766
```

now u can check problem i think is with spaces in beginning and in between columns

Comment: Do you need this in Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following using `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {if($3~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){a[i++]=$3}; next} \
     $3~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ {$3=$3+a[j++]} \
     1' file1 file2 > file3
```

Testing on sample input specified in comment:

```
$ cat file1
# comment here
90.0 355.0 1.54

$ cat file2
# comment here
90.0 355.0 0.550766

$ awk 'NR==FNR {if($3~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){a[i++]=$3}; next} \
?      $3~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ {$3=$3+a[j++]} \
?      1' file1 file2 > file3

$ cat file3
# comment here
90.0 355.0 2.09077
```

Comment: the answer i get in the third column is not the sum of the third columns in the other two files. for example file 1 has            90.0 355.0 1.54    file 2 has 90.0 355.0 0.550766   file 3 i get 90.0 355.0 3.08      which is not the sum  in column 3

Comment: @user1016914 it worked for me when I gave file1 and file2 same as your sample input and third row was multiplied by 2 as desired. In such case can you please update your question with content of file2 so that I can test it and tell you output at my end?

Comment: @user1016914 Here the assumption is your both lines match without any discrepancy in differing line numbers. I will update ans to remove that restriction.

Comment: no we want to add column 3  of both files and the result should be in column 3 of new file.  no  multiplication is required. everything else is perfect.

Comment: @user1016914 I have updated ans. Please check now. I was not multiplying. When I said multiplied by 2 means same data of file1 and file2 was being added since I didn't have I data for file2 and was giving file2 also as file1

Comment: everything is working except that the answer i get in colum 3 is not addition of the column 3 of the first two files.  use  only 1 row and put this for first file  90.0 355.0 1.54  and this  for 2nd file 90.0 355.0 0.550766   you will get this 90.0 355.0 3.08   in third file .which is not additon of third column. we should get this 90.0 355.0 2.09077

Comment: everything is working except that the answer i get in colum 3 is not addition of the column 3 of the first two files. use only 1 row and put this for first file 90.0 355.0 1.54 and this for 2nd file 90.0 355.0 0.550766 you will get this 90.0 355.0 3.08 in third file .which is not additon of third column. we should get this 90.0 355.0 2.09077

Comment: @user1016914 Did you check my updated ans? It's different than previous one.

Comment: i did and i get the answer i posted in my last post.

Comment: @user1016914 tried with your sample inputs. updated ans with this test. Please check.

Comment: @user1016914 Works fine for me. Are you sure you are using updated command?